# How do I disable Heroku PostgreSQL in review apps?

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

I am trying to enable review apps for a Rails application that uses MySQL, but Heroku keeps automatically installing **Heroku Postgres :: Database** as a resource and setting the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable for review apps. This causes Rails to assume I'm using PostgreSQL:

> Unable to load application: Gem::LoadError: Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded.

How can I disable automatic installation of the Postgres add-on and/or prevent `DATABASE_URL` from getting set in review apps?

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL is a heroku addon. If it's installed automatically, i assume you are generating an app.json file through the heroku dashboard and not manually.

What you need to do is to create an app.json file (at the root of your project), and to not put postgresql in the addons section. For example:

```
  "addons": [
    "your_included_addon_which_is_not_postgresql"
  ]
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. I already have an addons section that only lists rediscloud, and the PostgreSQL add-on is still being added.

Answer (score 0):

**Heroku PostgreSQL is enabled by default for review apps. To disable it, add the following to your app.json:**

```
"heroku-postgresql": {
"enabled": false
}
```

I Hope it would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Quoting Heroku docs:

> Developers using the heroku/ruby buildpack to deploy new applications who don’t want a Heroku Postgres database auto-provisioned can opt out by setting the HEROKU_SKIP_DATABASE_PROVISION environment variable.

```
heroku config:set HEROKU_SKIP_DATABASE_PROVISION=1
```

Full article available at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-database-provisioning#skip-auto-provisioning-a-database